# Query with single selection where statement and multiple selection arguments

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I need to implement the following query:

```
query(uri, projection, "parent_id=? ", selectionArgs, null)
```

... where `selectionArgs` is array of Strings of length, that changes dynamically with every use of this query. But it seems to return `null` as cursor.

Comment: you mean something like SQL: `parent_id IN (sA[0], sA[1], ... sA[n])`? if so you need to generate(use dynamic) `selection` too (not only `selectionArgs`(sA))

Comment: Yes,I guess it is exactly what I was looking for. How it should look like in case of android selection and selectionArgs?

Comment: you can generate `selection` like this `"parent_id in (?,?, ... , ?)"` or like `"parent_id=? OR parent_id=? OR ...  OR parent_id=?"` where count of `?` = selectionArgs.length() ...